# Google cloud vm stop or freeze when extracting a .7z file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, extract, 7zip

Resently I am working with Google Cloud Compute Engine to train a ml model
So I am tring to extract a .7z fike that has the data.
But it is too big and the machine even freezes or stops for uncatching error

I am using the Linux command below:

```
!7zr 'path of the file'
```

Any help to be able extracting the file ... Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is the file ? Do you have enogugh space on your VM's disk ??

Comment: It is big about ten gigs of compressed photos

Comment: Can you provide any logs when machine feezes and maybe serial port output (gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output --zone zone_name your_instance_name) ?

Comment: So it seems like I have solved the problem I was using a feee trail proxy so when the internet get bad the vpn chang the ip address and the kernel cannot reconnect so now I am using  paid one and it seems it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could try it by using GCS

Create a directory that only has the compressed file in it and nothing else,

yourdir/myfile.7z

Create an environment variable MYFILE=myfile.7z

Create a bucket on GCS using the gsutil cli:

```
gsutil mb gs://yourbucket/MY_DIR_FOR_ZIP_FILE
```

Next you upload the file to the bucket, like so

```
gsutil cp -m -v $MYFILE gs://MYBUCKET/MY_DIR_FOR_ZIP_FILE
```

Within the VM you can now download the file, again using gsutil cli

```
gsutil cp -m -v gs://MYBUCKET/MY_DIR_FOR_ZIP_FILE   /YOU_DIR
```

Then extract and also remove the compresses file,

```
7z x $MYFILE && rm -v $MYFILE
```

You should now have the uncompressed file on the VM

Make sure to use the -m flag this will perform a parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) copy.

Here is the reference [cp - Copy files and objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

[Using the gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil?hl=ru)

The instructions above assumes that the size of your data is less than 1TB, and also you are using a VM with a disk size large enough to accomadate the data.

If your data is more than 1TB, you will need to use [Transfer service for on-premises data](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/on-prem-overview).

The steps to follow when setting up transfer jobs are listed here 
[Creating a transfer job](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-jobs#create-transfer)